# Cover List<char> to string without using system namespace

Tags: c#, string, list

I'm in a unity class and i'm making a game and I need help on converting a list to a string, so I can save it using playerprefs. The issue is i'm using Random.range from the unityengine namespace and those two "randoms" can't coexist so I can't use namespace system. How can covert a List to a string?

Comment: Show the code. Do you mean `using` doesn't work? There is a number of options for you. But first show what you actually mean.

Comment: Uh, I imagine you're going to have a lot of problems if you "can't" use `System`. Can you expand on what the issue is? Perhaps you should use a fully qualified name for `Random.range` (i.e. prefix it with its namespace and a `.`)?

Comment: I didn't know I could do that

Comment: I'm relatively new too, you just have to make sure your question is properly worded and show you've actually tried to figure out the answer already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You absolutely **can** use System. It is the most fundamental C# namespace. You refer explicitly as System.Random.range or Unity.Random.range.

I highly recommend reading articles like
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/

Otherwise you could end up reinventing the wheel like above due lacking basic knowledge.

Comment: So now how to cover list<char> into string?

Comment: string letters = string.Join(' ', list);

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend that you not use a List datatype for storing characters as it is terribly slow and bulky. Rather make use of a StringBuilder to build up the characters. It is also fairly easy to query values from a StringBuilder and to get the final string result.